# vs2015 schema compare not deploying auto generated xmlserializer assembly

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, sqlclr

I have a sql database project in visual studio 2015, that includes a clr stored procedure that calls a webservice. I have configured the projects to auto generate the serialization assembly. This means in de output folder I get both a projectname.dll and a projectname.XmlSerializers.dll.

I use the visual studio schema compare function and that works fine in comparing and updating projectname.dll but it does not show projectname.XmlSerializers.dll which I have to update by hand every time.

How do I get the schema compare to recognize and update the projectname.XmlSerializers.dll file?

Comment: Have you included the generated **projectname.XmlSerializers.dll** file in the project? If not, you probably need to do this.

Comment: @srutzky, I have already tried that. Unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: For the properties of that DLL in the Project, is it set to **ModelAware** ?

Comment: @srutzky, No it was not set to modelaware. Setting that fixed it. I also had to move it to an seperate class library project, because the schema compare was looping with a source schema changed error when executing the update. If you make your comment into an answer I can mark it as such.

Comment: zu1b, I have added an answer based on my comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get SSDT to load a DLL that is not being created *directly from your project* into SQL Server, you need to do the following two steps:

1. Add the DLL to the Project (Add Existing Item)
2. For the properties of the newly included DLL, make sure that "Model Aware" is set to "true".